# Bitmap size much greater than file size from which it's loaded

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to retrieve an bitmap from image file in android:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
```

However, the size of the bitmap is more than double the size of file. Eg, for a file of size 520kb, the bitmap size is around 1.3MB. Is there a way I can get the bitmap of the same size as that of file?

Answer (score 5):

The bitmap size is pure memory data without compression. You can calculate the size with 4 bytes per pixel (with your settings).

Your file is probably in a compressed format like jpg. Without a compression it would take up the same space.

The reason why the bitmap is kept uncompressed in memory is basically the performance. You can read the data and work with it much faster in an uncompressed way. For example if you would like to see what color a specific pixel has, you would need to uncompress the data first. That takes time and the more pixels you check the more time it would take.

While reading the file from the storage, the uncompression just takes an ignorable amount of time compared to the complete reading process. So you will not have a big performance impact compared to "on demand" uncompression.

Comment: How can I pull up the bitmap from the file in a compressed format?

Comment: Based on your other comment: You can't read the file in a compressed format and set it to an ImageView to view it. You need to uncompress it like you already do. There is no other way to show it. You can read the file itself but it will just be some binary data that you can't use as a bitmap.

Comment: So is there a way I can reduce the size of a bitmap? My purpose is more than just displaying it in a view.

Comment: You can work with the sample size or you reduce the prefered config and use something like RGB_565 but you will lose quality and transparency. If you tell me what your other purpose is I might be able to help you further.

Comment: I was trying to add an image to a PDF, using android Kitkat and above PDFDocument API. With every bitmap being as huge as 3-4 MB or even larger for good resolution images, the PDF size becomes big enough to make the app crash after adding just a few such bitmaps. The image file size is small, but as soon as I take it into a bitmap, it becomes really huge, 2-3 times the size of original file.

Comment: I can't use inSampleSize, because then the size of page in PDF becomes really small, or I'll have to add a small image on a large page, which I don't want.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the PDF API but can't you do it one page at a time or incremental?

Comment: The pages can be added incrementally, but the entire document as to remain in memory till it's completed. So, even if a single page size is ~5MB, the document becomes pretty huge, and makes the app crash.

Comment: Well there is a hard memory limit. If the API supports it, you might make each page a single pdf and merge them later. If that is not possible you might use the NDK to develop the creation of the PDF or in the worst case make it somewhere in the cloud (upload bitmaps, create pdf, download). I am out of ideas beside that. Sorry, I can't help you further.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution with this API. Am trying the same with NDK now. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

try like this may help you,

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f,int WIDTH,int HIGHT){
 try {
     //Decode image size
     BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
     BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

     //The new size we want to scale to
     final int REQUIRED_WIDTH=WIDTH;
     final int REQUIRED_HIGHT=HIGHT;
     //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
     int scale=1;
     while(o.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_WIDTH && o.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_HIGHT)
         scale*=2;

     //Decode with inSampleSize
     BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     o2.inSampleSize=scale;
     return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
 } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
 return null;
}
```

Comment: That does not answer the basic question: Why is the bitmap size smaller in storage than in memory. Also you are not explaining what your code does and why it should be tried.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. Besides I don't want to increase or decrease the size of the image. I have a different use for the image than just showing it on an imageView. Hence, I want the bitmap to be same as it's present in the file.